# Different types of variable scales in a cluster analysis ( nearest neighbours and k-means)

Tags: clustering, k-means

I've to conduct a cluster analysis (nearest neighbours and k-means) with different types of variables (metric, nominal and binary). Which transformation is appropriate for conducting a cluster analysis with all variables included? My first thought was a z-transformation.

Many thanks in advance!! :-)

Comment: The question lacks focus. Suggest to re-word it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "nearest neighbor clustering".

K-means should *only* be used on continuous variables where the *mean* makes sense to use. It's a least-squares approach, where larger errors are considered more important than small errors; and which is theoretically appropriate if you have k well separated signals and i.i.d. Gaussian noise added...

So most likely, the assignment is bad.